# How to set terminal background color on linux terminal without using ncurses?

Tags: c, linux, colors, console

I've wrote a simple console program in C which uses ANSI escape codes to color its text.

Is there a way to temporarily set the background of the whole terminal to black and the default font color to light gray? Can this be reverted after the program ends?

I'd prefer to avoid using ncurses.

Comment: This question is so hard to read...that I didn't read it. Please format your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to go is to set the background colour of your text with ANSI:

For instance using:

```
echo -e "\e[37m\e[41m"
```

will give you blue text on a red background (you can use this to test the effect in dramatic, easy to see colours).

Whereas

```
echo -e "\e[97m\e[40m"
```

will set the foreground to white and the background to black for the duration of your program.

If you find that you're getting a kind of ugly transition zone between your background colour and the terminal's just print a sufficient number of newlines to wipe the whole screen.

To use this in C, you'll obviously want `printf` instead of `echo`.

The wiki page on [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) has additional information.

Comment: It looks like this is the only solution, thank you. I cannot upvote your post though, this karma -_-

Comment: @user1887348, you can accept my answer, though, if you hit the big check mark below the arrows next to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

How to do this depends on the terminal the user is using.  It may be ANSI, it may be VT100, it might be a line printer.  *ncurses* abstracts this horror for you.  It uses a database of information about how to talk to different kinds of terminal (see the contents of $TERM to see which one you are **currently** using) normally stored in `/lib/terminfo` or `/usr/share/terminfo`.

Once you look in those files, you'll probably want to reconsider not using *ncurses*, unless you have specific requirements to avoid it (embedded system with not enough storage, etc.)

Comment: I know that libncurses is amazing, but I think it just doesn't worth the effort. And then, one should have ncurses installed to be able to run a script which uses ncurses, it is not in a standard package.

Comment: The issue is that just echoing out constants like one answer suggested won't work if you're not using a terminal that understands those codes.  If that's good enough, then great.  But the terminfo databases (and ncurses as an interface to them) exist so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Yeah, dealing directly with the terminal is *less* 'standard' and portable than using a library which abstracts them, not more so. The fact that you can output terminal-specific escape codes with a standard function doesn't make what you're doing either standard or portable.