# How to change terminal bgcolor in a C program

Tags: c, background

I know that the background-color of some particular text can be altered like this:

```
printf("\033[031m bgColor is now red \033[047m And now white.\n");
```

But how do I change the bgcolor of the whole screen in terminal, no matter what?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set terminal background color on linux terminal without using ncurses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775570/how-to-set-terminal-background-color-on-linux-terminal-without-using-ncurses)

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color, then clear the screen. (Which you can do with `\e[H\e[2J`.) No, there isn't any way to do this without clearing the screen in the process.

Incidentally, you don't need the leading `0` in the argument to SGR (e.g, `031`). In fact, it may confuse some terminal applications — I'd recommend leaving it out (`\e[31m`, for instance).