# Changing terminal profiles in ruby or in a shell scripting language

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal

I made chess in terminal and it would be nice to be able to change terminal profile i.e. change the background color to white. Is there anyway to do this?Preferably in ruby. If it can't be done in ruby how about a shell scripting language?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set terminal background color on linux terminal without using ncurses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775570/how-to-set-terminal-background-color-on-linux-terminal-without-using-ncurses)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Terminal has no such thing as “global” background/foreground colors. They support changing these colors on the fly, though.

Unless you change colors in your chess game with `\e[` escape sequences, the task might be easily completed with [`tput`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tput.htm) shell command. From ruby it could be done with:

```
system("tput setab 7; tput setaf 0") # black on white
```

The colors-to-codes conversion might be done visually [here](http://terminal-color-builder.mudasobwa.ru/).