# Is it possible to change Linux Terminal text and background color using C?

Tags: c, linux

I want to change the colour of background UBUNTU TERMINAL with the help of c language .is this possible ?

Comment: `fopen("/etc/UBUNTU_TERMINAL", "w+")` and change configuration therein?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set terminal background color on linux terminal without using ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775570/how-to-set-terminal-background-color-on-linux-terminal-without-using-ncurses)

Answer (score 3):

You can use escape sequences

```
printf("\033[37m\033[41m"); // White foreground / Red background
printf("Something\n");
printf("\033[0m");          // Reset
```

This is the table of colors:

Foreground:

```
30 Black
31 Red
32 Green
33 Yellow
34 Blue
35 Magenta
36 Cyan
37 White
```

Background:

```
40 Black
41 Red
42 Green
43 Yellow
44 Blue
45 Magenta
46 Cyan
47 White

0 Reset all
1 Bold
```